# iPhone's Tone Color Change from an App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, application-settings

Recently, I have installed [Twilight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.lux) on my Android phone. Apparently is adds a color tone effect on the screen. Here are two screen shots taken from PlayStore.

[image: Screen Shots]

**Now my question is that is there a way to develop similar system display tone color set up application in iOS?**

Comment: No this is not possible with the official iOS SDK. Your app is sandboxed and cannot change system settings. Here is an app that does this by using unofficial code, https://justgetflux.com/sideload/  Be aware you can't not use this code for an app released in the AppStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible and I use an app that does this.

Have a look at https://github.com/anthonya1999/GoodNight, It's even open sourced.

However an app like this will most likely be denied from the App Store, but never the less it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as Apple restrict the developers to edit home screen. There are very limited features that we can access like Calendar, Gallery, etc. The above screenshot your are showing is related to Widget but there are no Widget concept in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Night Shift is supposed to bring something like this in iOS 9.3, though not to that extent.

I don't know of any public API that would allow an application to change that kind of parameter system-wise, though. Maybe in the Accessibility framework, but that would restrict it to app-wise, not system-wise.